# Jackson - Custom TypeId Resolver based on more than one property

Tags: java, json, jackson

I would like to deserialize JSON objects based on more than one property using Jackson; more specfically, I have objects for which, based on their ID field, the TYPE can be inferred.

This is needed for a REST API implementation, where two simplified situations can be observed :

1. the object is about to be created, in which case it doesn't have an ID yet, but the TYPE is required
2. the object is about to be updated, in which case the ID is provided, and the TYPE can be inferred

The object in the first case is like this :

```
{
    "type" : "dog",
    "name" : "rex"
}
```

The second case is like this :

```
{
    "id" : "D10000",
    "name" : "lady"
}
```

I'm looking for a way to deserialize both object to a Dog object.

Currently, the second case is serialized like his :

```
{
    "type" : "dog"
    "id" : "D10000",
    "name" : "lady"
}
```

... and it works just fine, but it's kind of redundant and I'm looking for a way to remove the "type" property in the second case.

So, first of all, is it possible using the current implementation of the Jackson library, and, obviously, if possible, how ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, implemented a workaround; posting it here for reference in case someone needs it someday.

The solution is to inject the required data when needed (the TYPE when can it's missing and can be inferred from the ID), but before each root node is parsed by the library.

```
// ObjectMapper om2;
// ...

final JsonNode jsonROOTNode = om.readTree(inputJSON);
Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> iterator = jsonROOTNode.fields();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Entry<String, JsonNode> e = iterator.next();
    if (e.getValue().isObject() && e.getValue().isContainerNode()) {
        injectData(e.getValue());
    }
    // rest of processing ...
}
```

and the data injection is performed like this :

```
void injectData(JsonNode _value)    {
    if (_value.has("TYPE")) {
        // we're good
    }
    else if (_value.has("ID")) {
        // infer and inject 'prefix'
        String _TYPE = ... // infer it from ID
        ((ObjectNode)_value).put("TYPE", _prefix);
    }
    
    // recurse
    Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> iterator = _value.fields();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, JsonNode> e = iterator.next();
        if (e.getValue().isArray()) {
            Iterator<JsonNode> arrayIterator = ((ArrayNode)e.getValue()).iterator();
            while (arrayIterator.hasNext()) {
                injectPrefixes(arrayIterator.next());
            }
        }
        else if (e.getValue().isContainerNode()) {
            injectPrefixes(e.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```